# How to force an application to run in the foreground, and be focused?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to force an application / file to run in the foreground and be focused when my computer starts up. I already have it automatically starting up with the computer (albeit ~5 seconds after login), but it runs minimized and thus unfocused. Any ideas? Preferably a BAT file.

I've used:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end

@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq m.bat" ^| find /I "m.bat"') do set pid=%%i
if "%pid%" == "" (
    %localappdata%\VOR\VOR.exe
) else (
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" "%pid%"
)
exit %errorlevel% 
endlocal

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end

var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
if (sh.AppActivate(WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) == 0) {
    sh.SendKeys("% r"); 
}
```

This opens and runs the correct BAT file, but it's minimized and in the background.

Comment: @Gerhard
Thanks! 
What if I also want it automatically focused?

Comment: @OutofBrainJuice , to focus on process window by batch use it's process id:
 `mshta vbscript:execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").AppActivate %pid%")(window.close)`

Comment: Read [Start Program on Top](https://superuser.com/questions/1658842/batch-file-start-program-on-top) on Super User.